# Is there any way to get first name , last name ( or phone number ) from twitter handle?

Tags: database, twitter

Problem Statement: Lets consider that you have huge customer data which has demographic information as firstname, lastname, phone and email. Now lets say that we have a twitter handle, then is there any way to tie that twitter handle to the proper contact/customer data present.

So basically I want to get phone number, email or firsname and last name so that match could be done in internal database to identify the existing customer.

Any pointers would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you want to proper view of customer information instead corrupt or lack information on your customers.

I don't think is that possible. Because twitter hiding telephone number or mail adress for securty and privacy.

Comment: Yes, I also think in the same way, but some how I want to identify the person. If there is a need of using other social medias to do so then it is also ok. But I am not able to figure out a proper way to do it. I am hoping to get some direction from community.